# Merge and concatenate 2 dataframes at same time

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I'm trying to concatenate 2 dataframes keeping only those rows where value of 2 columns is present in both dataframes. For e.g.

```
tp1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
     'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
     'B': [5, 4, 2, 7],
     'C': [2, 4, 9, 1],
     'D': [1, 9, 7, 0]
     })

tp2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
     'A': [8, 2, 3, 9],
     'B': [6, 4, 2, 4],
     'C': [2, 9, 9, 1],
     'D': [1, 9, 7, 0]
     })

tpOUT = pd.DataFrame(
    {
     'A': [2, 2, 3],
     'B': [4, 4, 2],
     'C': [4, 9, 9],
     'D': [9, 9, 7]
     })
```

if tp1 and tp2 are 2 dataframes then tpOUT is corresponding output.  I googled and found you can do this with pd.merge and pd.concat but cant seem to get it worked.

Comment: How are you getting the `tpOUT` to look like that? For example shouldn't your `A` row in `tpOUT` should either look like `[2,3]` or `[2,3,2,3]`?

Comment: Thats the whole problem. I know how to get [2,3] (which can be done using pd.merge) or [2,3,2,3] (which can be done using pd.concat). Column A and B are join keys. For keys (A:3, B:2) there is only one row but for key (A:2,B:4) there are 2 different values in the 2 dataframe.